# Adding minutes to a datetime in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, nullable

I'm still learning Linq and I came across a query I'm not able to get to work. I get an error about `DateTime?` does not contain a definition for `AddMinutes`. The Estimated_Out field is a nullable `DateTime` type. The `Offset_Dept_Time_Mins` is an integer field type.

Here is the SQL. It takes a field (`Estimated_Out`) and adds an accepted offset time (`Offset_Dep_Time_Mins`) divided by the minutes in a 24hr period and formats it as just minutes and seconds using a 24 hour format. An example of the returned time would be (17:45).

```
select to_char(ESTIMATED_OUT + (OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS/1440),'HH24:MI') as ETD
FROM TableName
```

Here is what I'm trying in Linq. In this example I'm first just trying to get it to add 10 minutes. Once I have that I was going to try to add the offset divided by the minutes of the day.

```
var result = (from f in TableName
                select new
                {
                    ETD=f.ESTIMATED_OUT,
                    ETD2=f.ESTIMATED_OUT.AddMinutes(10)
                }).ToList();
```

How can I add minutes to the estimated time and then how would i format it? I'm assuming I would have to convert it to a Sting somehow once the time is correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're comparing a `DateTime` to `DateTime?`. You need to check if f.ESTIMATED_OUT is null or get a default value, THEN do your comparison.

Second of all - if you are using the Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL, 
LINQ can't translate `.AddMinutes(10)` to the appropriate SQL Statement. Either do your date math outside of the LINQ statement or use the `SqlFunctions.DateAdd()` instead

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.dateadd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your nullable DateTime to a DateTime before you can add minutes to it:

```
var result = (from f in TableName
            select new
            {
                ETD=f.ESTIMATED_OUT,
                ETD2=((DateTime)f.ESTIMATED_OUT).AddMinutes(10)
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: What happens if `ESTIMATED_OUT` is `null`?

Comment: You would get an invalid operation exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `.AddMinutes()` on `DateTime?` because it's not `DateTime`. To do that you first have to get the internal value (`f.ESTIMATED_OUT.Value`) or some default value instead (using `GetValueOrDefault(x)`).

If you do choose to get the internal value without defaults, make sure you first filter out null rows:

```
from f in TableName
where f.ESTIMATED_OUT.HasValue
select new
{
    ETD=f.ESTIMATED_OUT,
    ETD2=f.ESTIMATED_OUT.Value.AddMinutes(10)
}).ToList();
```

If you want to use some default value instead, use this:

```
from f in TableName
select new
{
    ETD=f.ESTIMATED_OUT,
    ETD2=f.ESTIMATED_OUT.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now).AddMinutes(10)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: During my initial testing of this query I was using LinqPad set to "C# Statements". Now I'm actually applying this in my MVC project and I'm coming up with an error with the AddMinutes portion. The error says "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMinutes(double)' method, and this method cannot be translated to a store expression'.

Comment: I searched on this error and found some posts saying I should be using something like this System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes("DATETIMEHERE", 180). However, when I add this in LinqPad and MVC I get "DbFunctions does not exist in the namespace". Do I need to add a reference to something from NuGet? I've already installed EntityFramework through NuGet.

Second question, would the following statement be correct once I get all the references done correctly? ETD=System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(f.ESTIMATED_OUT, f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS + (f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS/1440))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I wanted to share what looks like is going to work based on everyone's suggestions.

ETD=f.ESTIMATED_OUT.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now).AddMinutes((double)f.OFFSET_DEP_TIME_MINS/1440).ToString(@"HH:mm")